# Is a versioning system or code repository necessary for a single developer?

Tags: php, svn

Why do I need to use a versioning system or repository? I code from scratch by myself and make web code changes along with database changes on reasonably large projects.

Comment: duplicate. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131282/would-it-make-sense-to-use-version-control-if-im-the-only-developer-closed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to do it - but I found out that it makes developing much easier.

It helped me

- to cut a lot of commented code out of my programs
- to get back to an old version (find out why it worked with an older version and doesn't work with the current one)
- with my backup strategy

After the learning curve I'm pretty sure you are going to like it

Comment: And to let me work on a branch (eg for a speculative development) while maintaining the trunk for the live system.

Answer (score 3):

**Definitely yes** - I have often coded on my own in the past, and a proper versioning system has proved invaluable on countless occasions.

Also see [Good excuses NOT to use version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132520/good-excuses-not-to-use-version-control)

Answer (score 0):

Change history and labels (tags in SVN) will not hurt you anyway. The repository will also protect you againt accidential losses due to erroneous code edits.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it'll offer you a versioning system which is often usefull, a backup of your application, a remote workspace to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side.
Period.

Answer (score 0):

For when you write something new, realise it is a parade of epic fail, and then want to go back to the old version with a minimum of fuss.

Yes - it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Version management can be done in multiple ways, svn, zipfiles with state of date dd-mm-yyyy), hell, even copy of

I would recommend a version management tool like SVN/CVS/Sourcesafe because it helps you understand what you did when and why, and gives you more control over your code (go back, branch/merge etc)

Comment: for a single developer a distributed source control system (Hg, GIT, ...) could be better because the repository is local and you don't need a server.

Comment: SVN can also work locally without an actual server; for example: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/quicksvn.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course. It will help you roll back to a previous version in case anything goes wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely need source control. It'll help if you need to go back to a previous version or accidently edit/delete files.

I'd say Continuous Integration wouldn't hurt either ... even for a one person project.

Answer (score 0):

It helps me at least in the following cases:

- Feel safe, e.g. if I accidentally remove a file (shit happens) I can just restore it
- Backups are easy to do

Anyway, all the answers say "yes", so, I guess you have already made a decision.